# No reconoce el modulo que estoy importando

Tags: python, django, modulos

Estoy tomando un curso de Django en python sucede que ya tengo mi app preparada con los debidos archivos y el servidor funcionando, pero cuando intento importar el archivo vistas al de url parece que no me lo reconoce que creo que es por eso que no me funciona la web cuando la inicio. No se por que no me reconoce el modulo como deberia importarlo entonces?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Julio c: Por favor, pasa el código en forma de texto para que sea más facil ayudarte. Imaginate que nuestras respuestas fueran en imagen, no querrías eso no?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes importar de la siguiente forma:

`from .views import hola_mundo`

Answer (score 0):

Eso es debido a que haces referencia a la carpeta y no al script, cuando lo importes del script views.py no es necesario que marques la extensión .py